# Como comprimir uma string para envio num campo do objecto JSON

Tags: java, json, string, utf-8, compressão

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver uma API em java, que retorna um objecto JSON.

Um dos campos do json final é texto longo, de dimensão desconhecida. O texto pode ou não conter caracteres especiais.

Estou a enviar a informação em bruto, numa string. Mas como a dimensão é desconhecida, tenho receio que exceda o aceitável. Alguma forma de comprimir essa informação?

Posso enviar a string convertida num array de bytes, qualquer linguagem/plataforma do lado do cliente consegue obter a string original?

O texto pode ter o tamanho de um documento com várias páginas. Quem sabe de um livro inteiro...

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual servidor window ou linux?

Answer (score 1):

Vou supor que você está trabalhando com um serviço REST.

Eu não me preocuparia em compactar a string na mão.

Ao invés disso me certificaria que o servidor suporte [Content-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) assim o cliente pode fazer a consulta e receber o dado compactado.
A grande maioria das bibliotecas de comunicação HTTP suportam a descompactação de forma transparente e os browsers também.

Comment: O serviço é uma servlet em java que retorna um objecto json. Construido com ajuda da lib GSON. Por isso, na pratica não é um  serviço RESTfull. Como habilito/certifico o suporte do Content_encoding no lado do servidor?

Comment: Chega definir response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip"); na servlet?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como é na prática, pois não estou acostumado com windows, mas talvez você possa aumentar o limite da sua publicação, dessa maneira não vai ter interrupções no processo de envio:

No servidor linux, é só ajustar os limites no php.ini ou no `.htaccess`:

```
post_max_size 800M
upload_max_filesize = 800M
```

No Windows acredito que seja algo similar a isso no web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="8000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Agora se pretende comprimir o json, você pode utilizar uma biblioteca para isso: [exemplo](https://github.com/tcorral/JSONC)